# How to mock class initializer for each method test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I'm having trouble cleanly mocking out the initializer for method unit tests.

```
import ipaddress
import logging

class MyClass:

  def __init__(self,
               ipaddr: ipaddress.IPv4Address,
               logger: logging.Logger) -> None:
      self.logger = logger
      self.handle = another.useful_method(ipaddr.exploded)

  def read_device_info(self) -> str:
      self.logger.debug('About to do something cool...')
      return another.method(self.handle, 'moar info')

  ...other methods...
```

In `my_module_test.py`:

```
import another
import ipaddress
import logging
import mock


class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @mock.patch.object(another, 'useful_method')
  def test_read_device_info_calls_useful_method(mock_useful_method):
      del mock_useful_method
      
      # How to simplify this instantiation overhead so not repeated?
      mock_addr = ipaddress.IPv4Address('127.0.0.1')
      mock_logger = mock.Mock(logging.Logger, autospec=True)
      mc = my_module.MyClass(mock_addr, mock_logger)
      mc.handle = 'a_handle'

      mc.read_device_info()
      mc.read_device_info.assert_called_once_with(mc.handle, 'moar info')
```

Comment: You are trying to test something (by the test function name) that actually does not happen directly. Maybe it is better to test that `MyClass` instantiation does that.

Comment: Throwing away the mock you receive from patching looks like an anti-pattern.

Comment: Finally you can use `setUp` and `tearDown` or your own helper methods to avoid repetition.